# SQL: How can I add a custom row before specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have a query and the result is like below:**

```
date      From
-----------------------
20        Airport
20        Vehicle
23        Person
24        Person
28        Person
28        Airport
```

**What I expected:**

```
date      From
-----------------------
20        Received From
20        Airport
20        Vehicle
23        Received From
23        Person
24        Received From
24        Person
28        Received From
28        Person
28        Airport
```

How do I add the "Received From" rows automatically?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What query did you use?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add **`Received From`** for all the each **`date`** column value and combine the actual table rows with this using **`UNION ALL`**. Then order the result using a **`CASE`** expression to come **`Received From`** value first.

**Query**

```
select t.`date`, t.`From` from(
  select `date`, `From` from `myTable`
  union all
  select distinct `date`, 'Received From' from `myTable`
) t
order by t.`date`,
case t.`From` when 'Received From' then 1 else 2 end, t.`From`;
```